# druid query count for multiple columns

Tags: nosql, druid

I have a query to count null values in a column. How can I adapt this to return count of null values across multiple columns? I have tried adding a list of fields e.g. [‘ip_address’,’user_agent’] to the dimension field but this didn’t work.

```
{"intervals":["2019-05-26T00:00:00.000Z/2019-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"],
"granularity":"all",
"context":{"timeout":60000,
"queryId":"71fe66b2-e654-45dc-8a8c-38ed160e79f5"},
"queryType":"timeseries",
"dataSource":"dataset-tablename”,
"aggregations":[{"type":"count",
"name":"count"}],
"filter":{"type":"and",
"fields":[{"type":"selector",
"dimension":"ip_address",
"value":"null"}]}}
```

this returns two columns,

> Timestamp | Count
>
> 2019-04-27T04:55:01.000Z | 246,933

which is the count of ip_address records with null values in the timeframe. How can I return the counts for other additional fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregators:

```
{"intervals":["2019-05-26T00:00:00.000Z/2019-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"],
"granularity":"all",
"context":{"timeout":60000, "queryId":"71fe66b2-e654-45dc-8a8c-38ed160e79f5"},
"queryType":"timeseries",
"dataSource":"dataset-tablename",
 "aggregations":[
     {"type":"filtered", "filter":{"type":"selector", "dimension":"ip_address", "value":"null"},
      "aggregator": {"type":"count", "name":"null_ip_address_count"}},
     {"type":"filtered", "filter":{"type":"selector", "dimension":"user_agent", "value":"null"},
      "aggregator": {"type":"count", "name":"null_user_agent_count"}}]
}
```

That is, instead of applying the filter to the entire query, apply the filter to individual aggregators.